# Android - PressedState is not updating when Button is inside scrollable column in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I started working with jetpack compose and I have a bug that I am not able to solve.

I have a simple button that should change the background color when its pressed. Everything works as intended as long as the button is not inside a lazy column or inside a regular column with scrollable modifier.

I made a small example case:

```
@Composable
fun ButtonTest() {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {

        val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()

        Log.d("ButtonTest", "IsPressed: $isPressed")

        Button(
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            onClick = {
                Log.i("ButtonTest", "Click")
            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = if (isPressed) Color.Red else Color.Green,
            )
        ) {
            Text(text = "TestButton", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
        }
    }
}
```

This works as intended. The Button changes his color and the Button the log file shows:

IsPressed: true

Click

IsPressed: false

Now when i add a scrolling modifier to the Column:

```
    modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())){ ...
```

It wont work anymore. The log only shows:

Click

IsPressed: false

and the button doesnt show the pressed color. Only if do a long press the pressedState changes to true. I also tried it with a lazy column but its the same issue.
How can i get the same behaviour for the button no matter if its inside a scrollable container or not?

Comment: So you just want the button to be red while you are pressing it and it, right?

Comment: In this example yes. I also need to change the text color in pressed state but its the same behaviour.

Comment: There is a delay with PressInteractions when you use them in scrollable containers. See this for more info: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203141462

Comment: I added a bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/283208637